# what does it mean when java applet has x on the webpage?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

i want uploaded a java applet to my webserver , on the webpage it gives me an x, im using internet explorer, what could be the problem thanks :))

Comment: your question is unclear. Could you give more details?

Comment: What is the URL of the broken applet?

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- your applet isn't loaded properly
- your applet isn't deployed properly
- your applet throws an error
- IE hasn't got proper Java support
- your webserver isn't configured properly

You'll have to do a bit more debugging and research to see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/redximage.xml

Basically, you are propably using a proxy which isn't configured in Java.

Answer (score 0):

APPLET puts an applet in your page. In its simplest use, APPLET requires the use of CODE (to tell what applet file to load), WIDTH (to tell how wide the applet should be), and HEIGHT (to tell how tall the applet should be). 
Source:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/applets/_APPLET.html

Check to see you got all the parameters right.